# Xcode not letting me add Outlets

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I created a project on Xcode (Xcode 11.0), but for some reason it won't let me add an outlet from `Main.storyboard`:

[image]
The picture shows that it only lets me add actions, and no outlets. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Also, I tried using the assistant editor but that doesn't work either:

[image]

In this picture, it has a bunch of random code. Also, the code is un-editable, so I can't do anything to it. Anyone know what to do?

Comment: Sometimes you have to add outlet by code and then connect it to the element in storyboard.

Comment: This happens when the class of the controller is not set to the UIViewController subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't showing it in your screenshot, but this looks like the expected behavior when the ViewController in your storyboard hasn't had its class set to your `UIViewController` subclass.  If you go into the Identity Inspector, after selecting your ViewController in storyboard, you can change the class to `ViewController` and that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your home work screen does not have correct class name. Open your story board then open identity inspector to set correct class name for your view controller.